# Blender particle mball simulation, does now work with time stretching

Tags: particles, collision, timeline

I have particle system, contained within the object mesh, with collisions, with 0.001 second timestep, 27 subframes. The particles object are mballs. All works well when i render movie without time stretching.

When I time stretch 1:4 the mballs go through the walls of the object. Its like the blender was simply regressing the posion of mballs, and allows them to go through the wall (mostly on 3 out of each 4 cycle frames), and recapps (at 4 back to cached position).

Any one knows what I am talking about ?

Comment: did you cache the simulation before time stretching?

Comment: Of course. With multiple extra frames (256)...